# How to bind TextBox to field of a class in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a custom property editor for vector value like this:

```
 public struct Float4
 {
      public float x,y,z,w;
 }
```

In some object, it will have a property like this:

```
public class SomeEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
      private Float4 prop;
      [Category("Property")]
      [Editor(typeof(VectorEditor),typeof(PropertyValueEditor)]
      public Float4 Prop
      {
            get{return prop;}
            set{prop = value ; NotifyPropertyChanged("prop");}
      }  
}
```

(I am using the WpfPropertyGrid from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87715/Native-WPF-PropertyGrid))

`VectorEditor` uses a DataTemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="VectorEditorTemplate">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <!--first use a ObjectDataProvider to get a `Type`-->
        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Float4}" x:Key='VectorType' >
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <local:GetFieldsConverter x:Key="GetFieldsConverter" />
    </DataTemplate.Resources>         

    <!--then use a Converter to create a ObservableCollection of `FieldInfo` from `Type`-->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VectorType},Converter={StaticResource GetFieldsConverter}}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <!-- this Converter will provider field name-->
                <local:GetFieldNameConverter x:Key="GetFieldNameConverter"/>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <!-- Other Elements -->
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock='Left' Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GetFieldNameConverter}}" Width="25" />
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

In this case, the Path in TextBox.Text is setted to `Value`, since it is a template, it doesn't know which field this Item is associated with.

So, how to make it associated with the field? and binding to it, so when this TextBox's value changed, it can raise a `PropertyChanged` event to the object which contains the `Float4`.

Comment: Why not to bind directly with property `Prop`?

Comment: @RohitVats `Path=Value` actually is binding directly to `Prop`,but i need each TextBox just edit each field of Prop.

Comment: what you exactly want to input/show in TextBox?

Comment: I want this Editor dynamic shows multi Textbox for editing each dimension of Vector (in this case is float4, but there are also float2, float3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least two things that will prevent usage of your `Float4` type in WPF:

- it's a **value type**
- the members are not **properties** but **fields**

So I fear you'll have to use a **proxy** for your values:

```
public class Float4Proxy : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Float4 float4;

    public float X
    {
        get { return float4.x; }
        set
        {
            if (value != float4.x)
            {
                float4.x = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("X"));
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

And in your XAML you'll be able to do such two-way bindings:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Path=Value.X}"/>
```

Comment: Still another problem is that it doesn't use the FieldInfo (or should be PropertyInfo )  provided by Items Source to access certain property.